# INCOMING: Wall of code for form and $_POST, not updating custom field's value

Tags: php, plugin-development

its been a long two days in an attempt program a plugin from scratch to provide a front end landing page with 2 forms.

Depending on which form the user wants to use, the form shall change a value in the database (add or create if nonexistent custom field "key"=>"value").

Without luck, many several changes were made to the forms and the functions associated to manipulate $_POST and getting its value etc and without success!

Is someone willing to take a look at my code below? The goal is to differentiate between two forms at the time of submission. After which, if the second submit button is pressed, a custom field value is updated in the wp_postmeta table.

```
<?php
$lucs_stored_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID);

// salt shaker, drawing straws, randomness
function lucs_random_thumbnail() {
        $lucs_random_image = rand(0,1);
        if ($lucs_random_image == 0) {
                $lucs_thumb_ra = plugins_url('/img/thumb0.png',__FILE__);
        } else {
                $lucs_thumb_ra = plugins_url('/img/thumb1.png',__FILE__);
        }
        return $lucs_thumb_ra;
}

// if participant has no featured image, display the following default image included in plugin
function lucs_get_featured_image() {
        if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
                the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail',array( 'class' => 'showcase-thumbnail' ));
        } else {
                echo '<img src="' . lucs_random_thumbnail() . '" class="showcase-thumbnail" alt="Organization">';
        }
}



/*START OF CONTESTANT FORM*/

if (isset($_POST['lucs_nonce_guest']) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['lucs_nonce_guest'],'post_nonce')) {

        if (isset($_POST['password']) && trim($_POST['password']) != '') {
                $lucs_form_details = array(
                        'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags($_POST['org_contestant']),
                        'post_content'  => sanitize_text_field($_POST['org_reason']),
                        'post_type'     => 'lucs_contestant',
                        'post_status'   => 'trash',
                        'comment_status'        => 'closed',
                );
                $lucs_if_posted = wp_insert_post($lucs_form_details);
                add_post_meta($lucs_if_posted,'org_contestant',sanitize_text_field($_POST['org_contestant']));
                add_post_meta($lucs_if_posted,'org_contact_person',sanitize_text_field($_POST['org_contact_person']));
                add_post_meta($lucs_if_posted,'org_zip',sanitize_text_field($_POST['org_zip']));
                add_post_meta($lucs_if_posted,'org_contact_phone',sanitize_text_field($_POST['org_contact_phone']));
                add_post_meta($lucs_if_posted,'org_contact_email',sanitize_text_field($_POST['org_contact_email']));
                add_post_meta($lucs_if_posted,'org_pets_rescued',sanitize_text_field($_POST['org_pets_rescued']));

                lucs_redirect_to_help();

        } elseif ($_POST['org_reason'] == '' || $_POST['org_contact_phone'] == '') {
                lucs_redirect_to_help();
        } elseif (isset($_POST['lucsy_form'])) {
                $lucs_form_details = array(
                        'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags($_POST['org_contestant']),
                        'post_content'  => '',
                        'post_type'     => 'lucs_contestant',
                        'post_status'   => 'pending',
                        'comment_status'        => 'closed',
                );
                $lucs_if_posted = wp_insert_post($lucs_form_details);
                add_post_meta($lucs_if_posted,'org_contestant',sanitize_text_field($_POST['org_contestant']));
                add_post_meta($lucs_if_posted,'org_contact_person',sanitize_text_field($_POST['org_contact_person']));
                add_post_meta($lucs_if_posted,'org_zip',sanitize_text_field($_POST['org_zip']));
                add_post_meta($lucs_if_posted,'org_contact_phone',sanitize_text_field($_POST['org_contact_phone']));
                add_post_meta($lucs_if_posted,'org_contact_email',sanitize_text_field($_POST['org_contact_email']));
                add_post_meta($lucs_if_posted,'org_pets_rescued',sanitize_text_field($_POST['org_pets_rescued']));
                add_post_meta($lucs_if_posted,'org_reason',sanitize_text_field($_POST['org_reason']));
                add_post_meta($lucs_if_posted,'org_participation',sanitize_text_field($_POST['org_participation']));
                add_post_meta($lucs_if_posted,'org_votes',sanitize_text_field($_POST['org_votes']));

                lucs_redirect_to_thanks();

        } elseif (isset($_POST['org_vote'])) {
                $submitted_array = array_keys($_POST['lucs_current_entry']);
                $lucs_hola = $submitted_array[0];

                function lucs_add_one_vote($value) {
                        //Get current bid
                        $myvote0 = get_post_meta($value, 'org_votes', true);

                        //Increase the bid, for example the amount here is 100?
                        $myvote1 = $myvote0 + 1;

                        //Update the database with the increased bid value
                        update_post_meta($value,'org_votes',$myvote1,$myvote0);

                        // In case you need to update another meta for the user, you
                        // can access the user ID with the get_current_user_id() function
                }

                lucs_add_one_vote($lucs_hola);

                lucs_redirect_to_thanks();
        }
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <title><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></title>
        <meta name="description" content="<?php if (!empty($lucs_stored_meta['contest_results'][0]) && $lucs_stored_meta['contest_status'][0] == 'Over') { echo $lucs_stored_meta['contest_results'][0]; } ?>">
        <meta name="author" content="<?php echo get_the_modified_author(); ?>">

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php
        switch ($lucs_stored_meta['contest_theme'][0]) {
                case "Plain":           echo esc_url(plugins_url('css/contest-plain/contest-plain.css', __FILE__)); break;
                case "Green Eggs":      echo esc_url(plugins_url('css/contest-green/contest-green-eggs.css', __FILE__)); break;
                case "Modern":          echo esc_url(plugins_url('css/contest-modern/contest-modern.css', __FILE__)); break;
        }
        ?>">

        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

<header class="contest-header">
                <div class="contest-logo">
                        <img alt="Contest hosted by example.org" src="<?php echo esc_url(plugins_url('img/logo.png', __FILE__)); ?>">
                </div>
                <div class="sarfb">
                        <div id="fb-root"></div>
                        <script>(function(d, s, id) {
                          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                          if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
                          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

                        <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/company" data-width="250" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="false"></div>
                </div>

        <div style="text-align:left;background-color: white; height:0px;border-bottom-color:rgb(204, 204, 204);border-width: medium medium 1px; border-style: none none solid; ">
        </div>

        <div style="text-align:left;background-color: white; border-top-color:rgb(229, 229, 229);padding-bottom:1px;border-width: 4px medium medium; border-style: solid none none; "></div>
</header>

<div id="contest-status">
        <p>This contest is <?php echo strtolower(sanitize_text_field($lucs_stored_meta['contest_status'][0])) ?>! <span class="light-end-date">End Date: <?php echo sanitize_text_field($lucs_stored_meta['contest_end_date'][0]) ?></span></p>
</div>

<div class="featured-image-container">
        <img alt="Contest brought to you by example.org" src="<?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) { echo wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id()); } else { echo sanitize_text_field(plugins_url( '/img/default-featured-image.jpg', __FILE__ )); } ?>" class="featured-image">
</div>

<div class="contest-share-container">
        <div class="contest-share-instruction">E-mail this contest to your friends and followers or Share!</div>
        <div class="contest-share-button">
                <a href="mailto:?body=%0D%0A%0D%0AStumbled upon this and thought you might be interested: %0D%0A%0D%0A<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink( $post->ID )); ?>&subject=Check Out This Contest" target="_blank" title="Email"><img src="<?php echo esc_url(plugins_url('css/contest-plain/img/email.png', __FILE__)); ?>"> E-mail </a>
        </div>
        <div class="contest-share-button">
                <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php esc_url(get_permalink( $post->ID ));?>&t=<?php the_title(); ?>" title="Share on Facebook"><img src="<?php echo esc_url(plugins_url('css/contest-plain/img/facebook_16.png', __FILE__)); ?>"> Facebook </a>
        </div>
        <div class="contest-share-button">
                <a href="javascript:window.location=%22https://twitter.com/share?url=%22+encodeURIComponent(document.location)+%22&text=%22+encodeURIComponent(document.title)" title="Tweet"><img src="<?php echo esc_url(plugins_url('css/contest-plain/img/twitter_16.png', __FILE__)); ?>"> Twitter </a>
        </div>
        <div class="contest-share-button">
                <a href="https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/confirm?hl=en&url=<?php esc_url(get_permalink( $post->ID )); ?>" target="_blank" title="Plus one this page on Google"><img src="<?php echo esc_url(plugins_url('css/contest-plain/img/plus_16.png', __FILE__)); ?>"> Google+ </a>
        </div>
        <div class="contest-share-button">
                <a href="//pinterest.com/pin/create/link/?url=<?php esc_url(get_permalink( $post->ID ))?>&description=<?php the_title();?>" title="Pin it"><img src="<?php echo esc_url(plugins_url('css/contest-plain/img/pinterest_16.png', __FILE__)); ?>"> Pinterest </a>
        </div>
        <div class="contest-share-button">
                <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=<?php esc_url(get_permalink( $post->ID )) ?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo esc_url(plugins_url('css/contest-plain/img/in_16.png', __FILE__)); ?>"> Linked in </a>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="lucs-frontform-title">WIN 5,000 Meals For Your Rescue</div>
<div class="lucs-frontform">
        <form action="" id="lucs-contestant-registration" method="POST">
                <fieldset>
                        <div class="lucs-label">
                                <label for="org-contestant"><b>Rescue</b> Organization Name</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="lucs-detail-input">
                                <input type="text" name="org_contestant" id="org-contestant" />
                        </div>
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset>
                        <div class="lucs-label">
                                <label for="org-contact-person">Contact Person [Name]</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="lucs-detail-input">
                                <input type="text" name="org_contact_person" id="org-contact-person" />
                        </div>
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset>
                        <div class="lucs-label">
                                <label for="org-zip">Zip Code</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="lucs-detail-input">
                                <input type="text" maxlength="5" name="org_zip" id="org-zip" />
                        </div>
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset>
                        <div class="lucs-label"><label>Preferred Contact Method</label></div>

                        <div class="lucs-label">
                                <label for="org-contact-phone">Phone</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="lucs-detail-input">
                                <input type="text" name="org_contact_phone" id="org-contact-phone" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="lucs-label">
                                <label for="org-contestant">E-mail</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="lucs-detail-input">
                                <input type="text" name="org_contact_email" id="org-contact-email" />
                        </div>
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset>
                        <div class="lucs-label"><label for="org-pets-rescued">Question for viewer</label></div>
                        <div class="lucs-detail-input">
                        <input type="text" maxlength="5" name="org_pets_rescued" id="org-pets-rescued" />
                        </div>
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset>
                        <div class="lucs-label"><label for="org-reason">Tell Us in 100-500 Words or Less Why You Could Use these 5,000 Meals.</label></div>
                        <textarea name="org_reason" id="org-reason" rows="4"></textarea>
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset>
                        <div class="lucs-detail-input">
                                <input type="hidden" maxlength="5" name="org_participation" id="org-participation" value="<?php echo the_ID(); ?>" />
                        </div>
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset>
                        <div class="lucs-detail-input">
                                <input type="hidden" maxlength="5" name="org_votes" id="org-votes" value="0" />
                        </div>
                </fieldset>

                <?php //the password is an anti-spam measure ?>
                <input type="text" name="password" id="password" autofill="off" style="display:none !important;" />

                <?php wp_nonce_field('post_nonce','lucs_nonce_guest'); ?>
                <button name="lucsy_form" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
</div>

<div class="tab-container">
        <a href="#" class="tab-left">A-C</a>
        <a href="#" class="tab-left">D-F</a>
        <a href="#" class="tab-left">G-I</a>
        <a href="#" class="tab-left">J-L</a>
        <a href="#" class="tab-left">M-O</a>
        <a href="#" class="tab-left">P-R</a>
        <a href="#" class="tab-left">S-U</a>
        <a href="#" class="tab-left">V-Z</a>
</div>

<div class="showcase-container">
        <?php
        // WP_Query arguments
        $lucs_current_contest_id = get_the_id();
        $args = array (
                'post_type'              => array( 'lucs_contestant' ),
                'post_status'            => array( 'publish' ),
                'pagination'             => true,
                'posts_per_page'         => '40',
                'ignore_sticky_posts'    => false,
                'order'                  => 'DESC',
                'orderby'                => 'date',
                'meta_query'             => array(
                        array(
                                'key'       => 'org_participation',
                                'value'     => $lucs_current_contest_id,
                                'compare'   => '=',
                                'type'      => 'NUMERIC',
                        ),
                ),
                'cache_results'          => true,
                'update_post_meta_cache' => true,
        );

        // The Query
        $lucs_query_participants = new WP_Query( $args );

        // The Loop
        if ( $lucs_query_participants->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $lucs_query_participants->have_posts() ) {
                $lucs_query_participants->the_post();
                // do something
                $lucs_single_contestant_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID);
                ?>

                <div class="showcase-individual">
                        <div class="showcase-thumbnail-container">
                                <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink($post->ID)); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title($post->ID); ?>">
                                <?php lucs_get_featured_image(); ?>
                                </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="showcase-title">
                                <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink($post->ID)); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title($post->ID); ?>"><?php echo the_title(); ?></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="showcase-intro">
                                <p><?php if (!empty($lucs_single_contestant_meta['org_reason'])) echo esc_html(wp_trim_words($lucs_single_contestant_meta['org_reason'][0],40,'...')) . '<a href="'. esc_url(get_permalink($post->ID)) .'"> Read More </a>'; ?></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="showcase-counter">
                                <form method="post">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="lucs_current_entry[<?php echo $post->ID; ?>]" value="lucs_vote">
                                        <button type="submit" name="org_vote">Vote</button>
                                </form>
                        </div>
                </div>

                <?php
                }
        } else {
                echo 'COMING SOON';
        }
        // Restore original Post Data
        wp_reset_postdata();

        ?>
</div> <!-- END OF class="showcase-container" -->

<footer class="contest-footer">

<div class="lucs-divider"></div>

<?php if ($lucs_stored_meta['contest_sponsor_visibility'][0] == 'Yes') { ?>

        <div class="sponsor-notice-box">
                <div class="sponsor-notice-title">
                        <div class="sponsor-notice-text"><b>Brought to you by </b><?php echo esc_html($lucs_stored_meta['contest_sponsor'][0]) ?>
                        </div>
                </div>
        </div>

<?php
} else {
 echo '';
}
?>

<p>By participating in this promotion you agree to the Official Rules.</p>
<p>This promotion is in no way sponsored, endorsed or administered by, or associated with, Facebook. By participating, you hereby release and hold harmless Facebook from any and all liability associated with this promotion.</p>

<div class="fb-like" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the question?  I think I know what you're hinting at but let's be specific.

Comment: Hi Milo, thank you. I found out the issue, see below: going to update the question. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the second form needs its own nonce and updated the code in the header of the page to do something if only the second form is submitted. See new code:

```
<?php
$lucs_stored_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID);

// salt shaker, drawing straws, randomness
function lucs_random_thumbnail() {
    $lucs_random_image = rand(0,1);
    if ($lucs_random_image == 0) {
        $lucs_thumb_ra = plugins_url('/img/thumb0.png',__FILE__);
    } else {
        $lucs_thumb_ra = plugins_url('/img/thumb1.png',__FILE__);
    }
    return $lucs_thumb_ra;
}

// if participant has no featured image, display the following default image included in plugin
function lucs_get_featured_image() {
    if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
        the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail',array( 'class' => 'showcase-thumbnail' ));
    } else {
        echo '<img src="' . lucs_random_thumbnail() . '" class="showcase-thumbnail" alt="Organization">';
    }
}

function lucs_add_one_vote($lucs_cid) {

    //Get current bid
    $myvote0 = get_post_meta($lucs_cid, 'org_votes', true);

    //Increase the bid, for example the amount here is 100?
    $myvote1 = $myvote0 + 1;

    //Update the database with the increased bid value
    update_post_meta($lucs_cid,'org_votes',$myvote1,$myvote0);
    lucs_redirect_to_thanks();
}



/*START OF CONTESTANT FORM*/

if (isset($_POST['lucs_nonce_guest']) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['lucs_nonce_guest'],'post_nonce')) {
    if (isset($_POST['password']) && trim($_POST['password']) != '') {
        $lucs_form_details = array(
            'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags($_POST['org_contestant']),
            'post_content'  => sanitize_text_field($_POST['org_reason']),
            'post_type'     => 'lucs_contestant',
            'post_status'   => 'trash',
            'comment_status'    => 'closed',
        );
        $lucs_if_posted = wp_insert_post($lucs_form_details);
        add_post_meta($lucs_if_posted,'org_contestant',sanitize_text_field($_POST['org_contestant']));
        add_post_meta($lucs_if_posted,'org_contact_person',sanitize_text_field($_POST['org_contact_person']));
        add_post_meta($lucs_if_posted,'org_zip',sanitize_text_field($_POST['org_zip']));
        add_post_meta($lucs_if_posted,'org_contact_phone',sanitize_text_field($_POST['org_contact_phone']));
        add_post_meta($lucs_if_posted,'org_contact_email',sanitize_text_field($_POST['org_contact_email']));
        add_post_meta($lucs_if_posted,'org_pets_rescued',sanitize_text_field($_POST['org_pets_rescued']));

        lucs_redirect_to_help();
    } elseif ($_POST['org_reason'] == '' || $_POST['org_contact_phone'] == '') {
        lucs_redirect_to_lost();
    } elseif (isset($_POST['lucsy_form'])) {
        $lucs_form_details = array(
            'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags($_POST['org_contestant']),
            'post_content'  => '',
            'post_type'     => 'lucs_contestant',
            'post_status'   => 'pending',
            'comment_status'    => 'closed',
        );
        $lucs_if_posted = wp_insert_post($lucs_form_details);
        add_post_meta($lucs_if_posted,'org_contestant',sanitize_text_field($_POST['org_contestant']));
        add_post_meta($lucs_if_posted,'org_contact_person',sanitize_text_field($_POST['org_contact_person']));
        add_post_meta($lucs_if_posted,'org_zip',sanitize_text_field($_POST['org_zip']));
        add_post_meta($lucs_if_posted,'org_contact_phone',sanitize_text_field($_POST['org_contact_phone']));
        add_post_meta($lucs_if_posted,'org_contact_email',sanitize_text_field($_POST['org_contact_email']));
        add_post_meta($lucs_if_posted,'org_pets_rescued',sanitize_text_field($_POST['org_pets_rescued']));
        add_post_meta($lucs_if_posted,'org_reason',sanitize_text_field($_POST['org_reason']));
        add_post_meta($lucs_if_posted,'org_participation',sanitize_text_field($_POST['org_participation']));
        add_post_meta($lucs_if_posted,'org_votes',sanitize_text_field($_POST['org_votes']));

        lucs_redirect_to_thanks();

    }
}
if (isset($_POST['lucs_grabbing_id']) && isset($_POST['lucs_nonce_voter']) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['lucs_nonce_voter'],'post_nonce')) {

    $lucs_myid = isset($_POST['lucs_grabbing_id']);

    lucs_add_one_vote(151);
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></title>
    <meta name="description" content="<?php if (!empty($lucs_stored_meta['contest_results'][0]) && $lucs_stored_meta['contest_status'][0] == 'Over') { echo $lucs_stored_meta['contest_results'][0]; } ?>">
    <meta name="author" content="<?php echo get_the_modified_author(); ?>">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php
    switch ($lucs_stored_meta['contest_theme'][0]) {
        case "Plain":       echo esc_url(plugins_url('css/contest-plain/contest-plain.css', __FILE__)); break;
        case "Green Eggs":  echo esc_url(plugins_url('css/contest-green/contest-green-eggs.css', __FILE__)); break;
        case "Modern":      echo esc_url(plugins_url('css/contest-modern/contest-modern.css', __FILE__)); break;
    }
    ?>">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

<header class="contest-header">
        <div class="contest-logo">
            <img alt="Contest hosted by SaveaRescue.org" src="<?php echo esc_url(plugins_url('img/save-a-rescue-logo.png', __FILE__)); ?>">
        </div>
        <div class="sarfb">
            <div id="fb-root"></div>
            <script>(function(d, s, id) {
              var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
              if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
              js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
              js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
              fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

            <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/savearescue" data-width="250" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="false"></div>
        </div>

    <div style="text-align:left;background-color: white; height:0px;border-bottom-color:rgb(204, 204, 204);border-width: medium medium 1px; border-style: none none solid; ">
    </div>

    <div style="text-align:left;background-color: white; border-top-color:rgb(229, 229, 229);padding-bottom:1px;border-width: 4px medium medium; border-style: solid none none; "></div>
</header>

<div id="contest-status">
    <p>This contest is <?php echo strtolower(sanitize_text_field($lucs_stored_meta['contest_status'][0])) ?>! <span class="light-end-date">End Date: <?php echo sanitize_text_field($lucs_stored_meta['contest_end_date'][0]) ?></span></p>
</div>

<div class="featured-image-container">
    <img alt="Contest brought to you by SaveaRescue.org" src="<?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) { echo wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id()); } else { echo sanitize_text_field(plugins_url( '/img/default-featured-image.jpg', __FILE__ )); } ?>" class="featured-image">
</div>

<div class="contest-share-container">
    <div class="contest-share-instruction">E-mail this contest to your friends and followers or Share!</div>
    <div class="contest-share-button">
        <a href="mailto:?body=%0D%0A%0D%0AStumbled upon this and thought you might be interested: %0D%0A%0D%0A<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink( $post->ID )); ?>&subject=Check Out This Contest" target="_blank" title="Email"><img src="<?php echo esc_url(plugins_url('css/contest-plain/img/email.png', __FILE__)); ?>"> E-mail </a>
    </div>
    <div class="contest-share-button">
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php esc_url(get_permalink( $post->ID ));?>&t=<?php the_title(); ?>" title="Share on Facebook"><img src="<?php echo esc_url(plugins_url('css/contest-plain/img/facebook_16.png', __FILE__)); ?>"> Facebook </a>
    </div>
    <div class="contest-share-button">
        <a href="javascript:window.location=%22https://twitter.com/share?url=%22+encodeURIComponent(document.location)+%22&text=%22+encodeURIComponent(document.title)" title="Tweet"><img src="<?php echo esc_url(plugins_url('css/contest-plain/img/twitter_16.png', __FILE__)); ?>"> Twitter </a>
    </div>
    <div class="contest-share-button">
        <a href="https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/confirm?hl=en&url=<?php esc_url(get_permalink( $post->ID )); ?>" target="_blank" title="Plus one this page on Google"><img src="<?php echo esc_url(plugins_url('css/contest-plain/img/plus_16.png', __FILE__)); ?>"> Google+ </a>
    </div>
    <div class="contest-share-button">
        <a href="//pinterest.com/pin/create/link/?url=<?php esc_url(get_permalink( $post->ID ))?>&description=<?php the_title();?>" title="Pin it"><img src="<?php echo esc_url(plugins_url('css/contest-plain/img/pinterest_16.png', __FILE__)); ?>"> Pinterest </a>
    </div>
    <div class="contest-share-button">
        <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=<?php esc_url(get_permalink( $post->ID )) ?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo esc_url(plugins_url('css/contest-plain/img/in_16.png', __FILE__)); ?>"> Linked in </a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="lucs-frontform-title">WIN 5,000 Meals For Your Rescue</div>
<div class="lucs-frontform">
    <form action="" id="lucs-contestant-registration" method="POST">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="lucs-label">
                <label for="org-contestant"><b>Rescue</b> Organization Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="lucs-detail-input">
                <input type="text" name="org_contestant" id="org-contestant" />
            </div>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <div class="lucs-label">
                <label for="org-contact-person">Contact Person [Name]</label>
            </div>
            <div class="lucs-detail-input">
                <input type="text" name="org_contact_person" id="org-contact-person" />
            </div>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <div class="lucs-label">
                <label for="org-zip">Zip Code</label>
            </div>
            <div class="lucs-detail-input">
                <input type="text" maxlength="5" name="org_zip" id="org-zip" />
            </div>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <div class="lucs-label"><label>Preferred Contact Method</label></div>

            <div class="lucs-label">
                <label for="org-contact-phone">Phone</label>
            </div>
            <div class="lucs-detail-input">
                <input type="text" name="org_contact_phone" id="org-contact-phone" />
            </div>

            <div class="lucs-label">
                <label for="org-contestant">E-mail</label>
            </div>
            <div class="lucs-detail-input">
                <input type="text" name="org_contact_email" id="org-contact-email" />
            </div>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <div class="lucs-label"><label for="org-pets-rescued">Number of Dogs/Cats this Rescue Organization has Saved This Year</label></div>
            <div class="lucs-detail-input">
            <input type="text" maxlength="5" name="org_pets_rescued" id="org-pets-rescued" />
            </div>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <div class="lucs-label"><label for="org-reason">Tell Us in 100-500 Words or Less Why You Could Use these 5,000 Meals.</label></div>
            <textarea name="org_reason" id="org-reason" rows="4"></textarea>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <div class="lucs-detail-input">
                <input type="hidden" maxlength="5" name="org_participation" id="org-participation" value="<?php echo the_ID(); ?>" />
            </div>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <div class="lucs-detail-input">
                <input type="hidden" maxlength="5" name="org_votes" id="org-votes" value="0" />
            </div>
        </fieldset>

        <?php //the password is an anti-spam measure ?>
        <input type="text" name="password" id="password" autofill="off" style="display:none !important;" />

        <?php wp_nonce_field('post_nonce','lucs_nonce_guest'); ?>
        <button name="lucsy_form" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>

<div class="tab-container">
    <a href="#" class="tab-left">A-C</a>
    <a href="#" class="tab-left">D-F</a>
    <a href="#" class="tab-left">G-I</a>
    <a href="#" class="tab-left">J-L</a>
    <a href="#" class="tab-left">M-O</a>
    <a href="#" class="tab-left">P-R</a>
    <a href="#" class="tab-left">S-U</a>
    <a href="#" class="tab-left">V-Z</a>
</div>

<div class="showcase-container">
    <?php
    // WP_Query arguments
    $lucs_current_contest_id = get_the_id();
    $args = array (
        'post_type'              => array( 'lucs_contestant' ),
        'post_status'            => array( 'publish' ),
        'pagination'             => true,
        'posts_per_page'         => '40',
        'ignore_sticky_posts'    => false,
        'order'                  => 'DESC',
        'orderby'                => 'date',
        'meta_query'             => array(
            array(
                'key'       => 'org_participation',
                'value'     => $lucs_current_contest_id,
                'compare'   => '=',
                'type'      => 'NUMERIC',
            ),
        ),
        'cache_results'          => true,
        'update_post_meta_cache' => true,
    );

    // The Query
    $lucs_query_participants = new WP_Query( $args );

    // The Loop
    if ( $lucs_query_participants->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $lucs_query_participants->have_posts() ) {
        $lucs_query_participants->the_post();
        // do something
        $lucs_single_contestant_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID);
        ?>

        <div class="showcase-individual">
            <div class="showcase-thumbnail-container">
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink($post->ID)); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title($post->ID); ?>">
                <?php lucs_get_featured_image(); ?>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="showcase-title">
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink($post->ID)); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_title($post->ID); ?>"><?php echo the_title(); ?></a>
            </div>
            <div class="showcase-intro">
                <p><?php if (!empty($lucs_single_contestant_meta['org_reason'])) echo esc_html(wp_trim_words($lucs_single_contestant_meta['org_reason'][0],40,'...')) . '<a href="'. esc_url(get_permalink($post->ID)) .'"> Read More </a>'; ?></p>
            </div>
            <div class="showcase-counter">
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <?php wp_nonce_field('post_nonce','lucs_nonce_voter'); ?>
                    <button type="submit" name="lucs_grabbing_id" value="<?php echo $post->ID ?>">Vote</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php
        }
    } else {
        echo 'COMING SOON';
    }
    // Restore original Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();

    ?>
</div> <!-- END OF class="showcase-container" -->

<footer class="contest-footer">

<div class="lucs-divider"></div>

<?php if ($lucs_stored_meta['contest_sponsor_visibility'][0] == 'Yes') { ?>

    <div class="sponsor-notice-box">
        <div class="sponsor-notice-title">
            <div class="sponsor-notice-text"><b>Brought to you by </b><?php echo esc_html($lucs_stored_meta['contest_sponsor'][0]) ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php
} else {
 echo '';
}
?>

<p>By participating in this promotion you agree to the Official Rules.</p>
<p>This page is powered by <a href="http://">LUCS</a>. LUCS does not endorse, sponsor, or administer this.</p>
<p>This promotion is in no way sponsored, endorsed or administered by, or associated with, Facebook. By participating, you hereby release and hold harmless Facebook from any and all liability associated with this promotion.</p>

<div class="fb-like" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
</footer>

</html>
</body>
```